# Safety circuit for N-channel MOSFET failure (internal short) of buck converter

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, buck

Consider the following simple low-side N-channel MOSFET based buck converter:
[image]

One of the dangerous situations for the load connected to this kind of buck converter (especially if the load is a battery that needs to be charged) is when the MOSFET fails and becomes shorted, resulting in a higher voltage at the output. For the sake of this example, lets say the input voltage is around 28 V and the output is around 18 V. I want to have (but couldn't come-up with) a simple safety circuit that disconnects the load if the MOSFET fails and becomes shorted. By simple I mean the safety circuit should not be dependent on any micro-controller/software.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [crowbar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowbar_(circuit)) circuit.
It will turn on the triac above a certain voltage, and the triac will stay on until the current stops either by fuse or power off.
There must be enough energy to operate a fuse.

[image: crowbar circuit]

You will need a fuse or other sacrificial component to interrupt the current or the triac will need to endure the short circuit current indefinetely.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this crowbar circuit into something that can use a relay to control the output of the buck converter instead of creating a short circuit?

Comment: @irshukhan you can always create voltage monitor

Comment: sorry couldn't get what you mean by voltage monitor. Could you explain a bit?

Comment: @irshukhan you can make a windowed voltage comparator with a relay as output, it will need more components, be slower, use more power and be less reliable than the crowbar. Buy it wouldn't short anything. You can also get IC voltage monitors that could drive a mosfet or smart switch. Options enough, but they are not a true protection mechanism for failure. (eg: they're not latching, the fuse is)

Comment: A relay may not be fast enough, a crowbar is the safest solution. There was an IC that I used many years ago, but it seems to be obsolete, MC3423.

Comment: @Mattman944 irshukhan doesn't want to create a short circuit. The crow bar inherently works because of a short circuit. A relay could break the circuit without creating a short.

Comment: @MOSFET: OP appears to be concerned about the case when a relay (solid state relay) fails shorted and does not disconnect the load.  Adding a relay makes it safer (single fault tolerant) but then one could also simply use two NFETs in series so that if one fails the other still operates.

Comment: A triac is typically used in AC circuits. For DC is it not more usual to use a thyrister?

Comment: @irshukhan are you trying to detect if someone puts the magic smoke back in the MOSFET? Once the buck converter is broken, it's broken. Someone has to replace the whole converter to make it work again, and the new converter has a new fuse, so the output is on.

Comment: @user253751 i am aware that once the MOSFET fails its needs to be replaced. I am just concerned whether relying on a crowbar as a safety mechanism is a good idea from a safety perspective or does it give rise to more safety concerns (e.g., fire hazard). In other words, i am unable to understand whether it is more risky (dangerous) to rely on a short circuit mechanism (crowbar) to blow up the fuse OR to use a relay mechanism (energized: output on; deenergized: output off) which is slower but avoids short circuit. I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: A properly designed crowbar is not unsafe.  They are used to improve safety.  The fuse is designed to fail, and once it clears, the entire circuit is powered off. 

Also, FET failure should not be a common occurrence if the recommended operating conditions are maintained, including SOA.

Answer (score 2):

Some gate drivers (which you need most of the time anyway to drive a power MOSFET) can detect a short-circuit and activate a fault signal, with this fault signal you can open a relay disconnecting the load.

For an example of such a gate driver, take a look at this [App Note](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Low-side_driver-ApplicationNotes-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46265487f7b01655c2d8358778a) for instance (starting in page 14). If you look at the datasheet of the 1ED44176N01F referred there, you'll see in the block diagram that this feature is basically a comparator with some basic logic (SR flip flop), the input to the comparator is a voltage drop measured in a shunt resistance in series with the MOSFET.